# An inequality of dimension and depth of Noetherian local rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Here is my question:

> Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring with ideal $I\subset\mathfrak m$. Do we have $$\mathrm{depth}_IR+\dim R/I\geq\mathrm{depth}R?$$

If we have, then this is stronger than $\mathrm{depth}R\leq\dim R$ since we have $$\mathrm{depth}_IR+\dim R/I\leq\mathrm{height}(I)+\dim R/I\leq\dim R.$$
But I don not whether this is true or not! If this is not true, is there some counter-examples?

---

Thank you for your any help!

Comment: Sorry, what is $\operatorname{depth}_I R$? Did you mean $\operatorname{depth}_R I$? You need an underlying ring to calculate the depth of a module!

Comment: @PCeltide The $\mathrm{depth}_IR$ is the maximal length of $R$-regular sequence in $I$.

Comment: This may not answer your question, but for a sufficiently nice ring (say, excellent and equidimensional, maybe not necessary) then $\operatorname{depth}(R)\le \operatorname{depth}(R_\mathfrak{p})+\dim(R/\mathfrak{p})$ for all $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ (in fact, $\operatorname{depth}(R)$ is equal to the infimum of the right hand side). I believe this to be an even more refined version of your inequality, but I don't see an immediate reduction of it which implies your inequality.

Comment: @walkar Yes, this is [Tag 0FCC](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FCC). But I don't know how to use this... May be we can take infimum in $\mathfrak p\in V(I)$?

Comment: Oh wow, I'm surprised that it has essentially no hypotheses. I'll keep thinking of how to use it.